# Thank you note was never answered

Tags: email, communication

I recently sent a thank you note to one of my college professors via email and never got a reply from her. I have not heard from her in a week and being that she is retired I would have thought that as a courtesy, she could have replied to my email (i.e. thank you for your kind words). Is it normal for retired professors to not reply to these sorts of emails?

Comment: Perhaps, since she is retired, she does not check email very often, or is on travel, or who knows what...

Comment: Yes, thank you, Jon. I have also emailed to Office Assistant at this Department asking him how I can contact Professor. I don't know what is going on there, I got no reply, either. Maybe  they are all on vocation, Very strange

Comment: Many codes of etiquette say that people should not reply to thank you notes.  Just let it go.

Comment: Did you plan to reply to her thank you note for your thank you note?

Comment: maybe. It would depend on what she replied back. If she replies just "Thank you", then thanking her back would create a loop.

Comment: Is your note special, for example very long and poetic or refers to a something a long time ago like "thank you for your help during my freshman course, I now graduated with a PhD and would never have passed my Bachelor's without you"? Did you have a special (academic) relationship with her (she being your supervisor)?

Comment: Moreover, you write you have a question - what exactly is your question?

Comment: She helped me in her class.So, it does refer to something she did for me a long time ago.   Saw an article about her on the internet,  just wanted to say, "thank you."   Told her how much I enjoyed her lectures on certain topics. My question was -would it be an appropriate gesture, on her part, to reply back?

Comment: Are you sure she remembers you? Moreover, I don't know if you do - but you should definitely not get hung up on such things. There are more and less polite people in the world and you need to just forget about some impolite things.

Comment: that I don't know, but, I reminded her what class I took and my name. I think that just replying back something like  "thank you for your kind words." Would be enough as a gesture of politeness.

Comment: I don't know where you are in the world but it was Easter last weekend and here in the UK that meant a 4 day weekend. A lot of people take some extra days off too so they have a week of holiday-- maybe she is just away at the moment.

Comment: It would seem to be overly high of an expectation to always have a reply to your thank you note.  Forget it and move on.

Answer (score 10):

I wouldn't say that. Professors really appreciate the "thank you" messages but replying to them makes some of us a little uncomfortable at times. Sometimes we don't know what to say also.

One thing for sure: it makes us quite happy and sometimes a little embarrassed.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 main reasons why she may not have responded.

**1.** The email you sent was to an address she no longer has access to, or does not check, because she is now retired.

**2.** As Elkady says above, some professors don't know how to reply or potentially does not see a reason to reply.

**3.** She did ignore you.

1 and 2 are the most likely reasons here. It isn't uncommon for professors to not reply all the time. In your case, don't do anything. Sending a follow up email asking why she didn't reply will be considered rude.